django NoReverseMatch at /display/displaymyoperations/
hi everybody i have a django project i saved a URLs on database and i want to show every urls that the user has visit and his evaluate i have tow roads for that the road one youtube and the road two any site on the web but i delver a mistake error NoReverseMatch at /display/displaymyoperations/
Reverse for 'display_video' with keyword arguments '{'emburl': 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['display/display/(?P[^/]+)/$'] this is the templet i make it  {% for display_datum in display_data %} {% if display_datum.displays.isyoutube %} {% with video_id=display_datum.displays.url|slice:"-11" %} <a href="{% url 'display_video' emburl=video_id %}" class="btn mt-3 w-100">{{ display_datum.displays.text }}</a> {% endwith %} {% else %} <a href="{% url 'display_web' emburl=display_datum.displays.url %}" class="btn mt-3 w-100">{{ display_datum.displays.text }}</a> {% endif %} <strong>{{ display_datum.choosenum_text }}</strong> {{ display_datum.puplish_date }}<br> {% endfor %} and this is an example of what i want to slice   https://www.youtube.com/embed/jE1loGZGQZI
and this is views.py `def displaymyoperations(request):
# استرداد بيانات المستخدم الحالي
current_user = request.user
userprofile=UserProfile.objects.get(user=current_user)
# استعلام بيانات العروض التي قام المستخدم بتقييمها
display_data = Display_Data.objects.filter(users=userprofile).order_by('-puplish_date')
#display_data = Display_Data.objects.filter(users=userprofile)
# تحويل قيمة التقييم إلى نص وصفي
for display_datum in display_data:
    if display_datum.choosenum == 1:
        display_datum.choosenum_text = "نجاح"
    elif display_datum.choosenum == 2:
        display_datum.choosenum_text = "فشل"
    elif display_datum.choosenum == 3:
        display_datum.choosenum_text = "بحاجة إلى مال"
    elif display_datum.choosenum == 4:
        display_datum.choosenum_text = "بحاجة إلى أدوات"
    else:
        display_datum.choosenum_text = "مؤجل"


# تحضير سياق العرض (context)
context = {
    'display_data': display_data,
}

# عرض القالب (template) مع البيانات
return render(request, 'display/displaymyoperations.html', context)

and this is urls.py `urlpatterns = [
path('display/str:url/', display_video, name='display_video'),
path('display_web/str:url/', display_web  , name='display_web'),``
i try to take from filed of youtube the last numbers and characters   but it did not work
